# Where can I take ICAO Aviation English proficiency test?

Tags: pilots

Do you know some pages which listing the place I can take ICAO Aviation English proficiency test or useful pages?
I sent e-mail to ICAO and search it many times. But, still I can not obtain good information.

Comment: ICAO doesn't issue licenses or do training directly, their member countries do that. That means the best idea is probably to contact the aviation authority of your country, but if you can tell us which country you're in then someone may be able to help.

Comment: Then, I can understand there are no  lists. USA or Asian countries like Taiwan, China, Hong kong, Japan will work for me.

Comment: There is no central list. Many places that offer international flight training also offer Aviation English courses. Check out whichever ones are near you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICAO does not offer testing or training itself, only sets standards that most countries adopt (sometimes requiring stricter even) as their own.

The relevant aviation authorities in your country might have such a list of places authorised to offer the test, if you can't contact them directly any flight school will be able to assist either directly or by bringing you into contact with another school that offers theory classes.

E.g. in the Netherlands EASA rules apply, which sit on top of ICAO rules, and are enforced by the Dutch ministry of transportation. Examination is handled by the CBR (which also handles drivers' licenses). Schools offering theory classes can enroll you in the exams and tend to have the facilities to take the exams (which are all remote/computer based these days, in the past you had to make your way to one of a very small number of offices on a limited number of available exam days each year).

Similar arrangements are to be expected in other countries.

Comment: Thank you. I'll contact the relevant aviation authorities!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are from, but if you are near Germany, "Lufthansa Aviation Training/European Flight Academy" conducts these tests on a regular basis. Just give them a call and maybe you can participate in one.